# className, tagName etc in selenium java

Tags: selenium, button

I tried to click the button using selenium.
The code of the button is as follows:

```
<button class="btn btnSearch" type="button" data-gtm="wyszukiwarka" szukaj">Szukaj</button>
```

I do not see any id?
It's possible to click the button like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are many ways to click a button without name and ID, and there are many duplicates of this question, my advise is always to use a relative XPath expression when there is no name or ID.

You can click the button with:

```
findElement(by.xpath("//button[@class='btn btnSearch']"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` provided to click on the button with text as **Szukaj** you can use the following line of code :

- Java :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btnSearch' and contains(.,'Szukaj')]")).click();
  ```
- Python :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btnSearch' and contains(.,'Szukaj')]").click()
  ```
- Dot Net :

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btnSearch' and contains(.,'Szukaj')]")).Click();
  ```